# ng2-smart-table : how to use css?

Tags: css, angular, ng2-smart-table

anyone can help me how to use CSS to the ng2-smart-table compoment?

I wuold like to customize pagination , title, thead, tbody

thanks in advance
Andrea

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use below configuration in the settings object

```
attr: {
        class: 'table table-bordered'
      }, //this is for getting default table class
```

and

```
 :host /deep/ ng2-smart-table { 
    font-size: 16px; 
}//this for custom css
```

Example :

```
settings = {
  columns: {
    id: {
      title: 'ID'
    },
    name: {
      title: 'Full Name'
    },
    username: {
      title: 'User Name'
    },
    email: {
      title: 'Email'
    }
  },
attr: {
        class: 'table table-bordered'
      }
};
```

Comment: thank you so much, do yo know how can i put a style for the item selected?